# One to many left join queries

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

Hi everyone,
            I am new to hibernate JPA. Below is the relationship I defined between Entities A and B.

Here's the code for class `A`

```
class A{

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private Long id;

   @Column(name = "col_1")
private Long col1;

   @Column(name = "col_2")
private Long col2;

   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy = "a")
private List<B> bList= new LinkedList<B>();

   public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

   public List<B> getBList() {
    return bList;
}

public void setBList(List<B> bList) {
    this.bList = bList;
}

}
```

And here's the code for class `B`

```
class B{

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private Long id;

   @NotNull
@ManyToOne(optional=false)
@JoinColumns(value = { @JoinColumn(name = "col_1", referencedColumnName="col_1"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "col_1", referencedColumnName="col_2") })
private A a;

    @Column(name = "col_1")
private Long col1;

    @Column(name = "col_2")
private Long col2;

    public A getA() {
    return a;
}

public void setA(A a) {
    this.a = a;
}

     public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
}
```

I have a `crudrepository` interface for `A`. When I run a crud method which loads `A` entity, I see one left outer join query for each record present in `B` mapped by `col_1` and `col_2` columns of `A`. All these queries are redundant. I am expecting only one left outer join query to be executed. This is causing timeouts in my application. Thanks for you help :)

Comment: Do you have indexing on these two columns?

Comment: @KhueVu : Yes, I have indexes on these two columns in A as well as B, in A these columns together create the unique constraint.

Comment: JPA requires relationships to use the pk because it allows caching entities on the pk.  I do not know Hibernate internals, but it could be mapping it this way forces it to go to the DB to resolve the reference each time it is encountered while building your objects, instead of being able to look it up from the cache.  If col_1+col_2 are unique, you might try making them the PK instead to see if it helps.

Comment: @Chris: Thanks a lot..that worked!!! Will the queries fetch from cache only when we query with the primary key? Please clarify.

Comment: Hi, you have indexes on two different columns A and B rather than an index (A, B). When you search without an index, it is row by row search.

Comment: @KhueVu: I have an index on (A,B)